# Cakephp 2.0 hasAndBelongsToMany Model error

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I baked an images, galleries and galleries_images model and linked these with the HABTM association however I believe I made an error somewhere.

The following error is returned when trying to access the images/view/1 page.

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'GalleriesImage.image_id' in 'on clause'

SQL Query: SELECT `Gallery`.`id`, `Gallery`.`category`, `GalleriesImage`.`id`, `GalleriesImage`.`galleries_id`, `GalleriesImage`.`images_id` FROM `galleries` AS `Gallery` JOIN `galleries_images` AS `GalleriesImage` ON (`GalleriesImage`.`image_id` = 1 AND `GalleriesImage`.`gallery_id` = `Gallery`.`id`)

I believe the last `GalleriesImage`.`gallery_id` = `Gallery`.`id` should be
`GalleriesImage`.`gallery_id` = 1

I am pretty new to this so any hints as to where I should be looking or any explination would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hasAndBelongsToMany is basically just two different sets of hasMany and belongsTo.

My own cakephp webapp with over 30 odd tables has led me to forego using hasAndBelongsToMany.

I chose the hasMany through the JOin model. See [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model)

Also in order to better answer your problems, it is better that you reproduce your models relations and the ->save() code in your question.

Having just the sql statements is not enough.